# How to read file from Makefile?

Tags: makefile, mobile-devices

I am using GNU Make to build a multiple-directory project. 
My question is how can I use single makefile to build multiple devices? 
e.g. My application has to run on various X,Y,Z mobile devices each having different properties like screensize, keyboard type, platform version etc. I have to pass `make -f <makefilename> <targetname>`. Here targetname can be device name and model like Samsung CorbyPlus, but my makefile has to go to particular dirname of samsung and open the .txt file or so where all above properties are defined. I have to read all of them during build time and access in my code through some macros/defines/flags.

Can anyone suggest how to do this? Even better solution for my requirement will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using configuration makefiles. For example, suppose you have several device with its configurations:

**config_device1.mk**

```
OPTION1=yes
OPTION2=0
```

**config_device2.mk**

```
OPTION1=no
OPTION2=1
```

Then you can conditionally include them into base makefile using special parameter passed from command line (**make -f makefile DEVICE=dev_type1**) and use options from configuration files and process them:

**makefile**

```
ifeq ($(DEVICE),dev_type1)
include $(CONFIG_PATH)/config_device1.mk
endif

ifeq ($(DEVICE),dev_type2)
include $(CONFIG_PATH)/config_device1.mk
endif

ifeq ($(OPTION1),yes)
CFLAGS += -DBUILD_OPTION1     
endif

CFLAGS += -DBUILD_OPTION2=$(OPTION2)
```

BTW, for a long perspective (if you don't have time constraints now) it's better to use some of existing build system, read its manual and stick to its methodology.

Comment: Without the `ifeq` functions, you could use a naming convention: `include $(CONFIG_PATH)/config_$(DEVICE).mk` for example.

Comment: Thanks. Right, it's just an example and all depends on particular build environment, architecture, conventions used in a project (which should be developed and followed by all participants)

Comment: Can anyone tell me how can I carry the value of assigned macro/variable/flag in makefile to my code? 
e.g. in above snippet if I assign SCREENSIZE=17X220 and i want to take this SCREENSIZE macro value in my code, how can I?
Because rest else 0/1, true/false values are generally being checked in code through #ifdef or #ifndef etc.. only.

Comment: You can assign just as in the above example: CFLAGS+=-DSCREENSIZE=170x220, but in this case you have to parse 170x220 in your code as string. OR you can set CFLAGS+=-DSCREENHEIGHT=170 -DSCREENWIDTH=220 and then use SCREENHEIGHT and SCREENWIDTH as macros in your code directly.